# Looping through XML elements using XSLT and calling another xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

I am looping through different XML elements using XSL transformation. Following is my sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Alerts>    
      <AlertType>
         <AlertTypeOne>
            <NewAlert></NewAlert>
         </AlertTypeOne>                
      </AlertType>

      <AlertType>
         <AlertTypeTwo>
            <NewerAlert></NewerAlert>
         </AlertTypeTwo>            
      </AlertType>

      <AlertType>
         <AlertTypeThree>
            <OldAlert></OldAlert>
         </AlertTypeThree>              
      </AlertType>
</Alerts>
```

Following is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Alerts</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Credit Monitoring Activity</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum <br/>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//Alerts/AlertType">
                                <!--logic -->
                            </xsl:for-each></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am iterating through different AlertType tags. AlertType tags may contain different xmls (not related to each other), based on the first element inside  tag, I want to call appropriate xsl file and pass the xml contents to it (just like a method call in java).

Currently, I am not able to access immediate child of AlertType tag, let alone matching it. Can anyone please help on how to access child node? Also, based on matching results (using for each) I want to call different xslts. Any idea how to do it?

***Edit***
As xml contains information of different alerts, I want to display an HTML file comprising of multiple tables (one table per alert).
According to different data in the tags, the name and values of columns may be different.

This is how an HTML should look like:

Credit Monitoring Activity

AlertTypeOne
Name    Address City    State

Data    Data    Data    Data

AlertTypeTwo

Qualification   Designation Role

Data    Data    Data

AlertTypeThree

Credit  Debit

Data    Data

Comment: This question is too vague. Please show a **representative** XML input sample (one without `<!--Some info-->`, but with the actual elements you'd like to retrieve) and your **expected** XML output.

Comment: Edited.
Basically, I have different xsl files to process <NewAlert>, <NewerAlert> and <OldAlert> xmls, I need to call appropriate xsl file depending upon the name of the tag I encounter during looping. I want to convert all xmls into a single HTML.

Comment: Then, why don't you show those different XSLT files?

Comment: I need to consolidate all the data into single file.

Comment: You still do not show the HTML output you expect. And you are using the terms "xmls", "xsl" and "files" in a slightly confusing way. Do you have multiple XSLT stylesheets or multiple XML input files or something entirely different?

Comment: "*I want to display an HTML file comprising of multiple tables (one table per alert).*" Please show us an XML document that contains multiple (at least two) alerts, **including their contents**. Then explain how each table needs to be constructed based on the alert contents - preferably by showing the resulting HTML that you are hoping to get.

Comment: By "*resulting HTML*" I meant the actual **code**.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about your solution rather than identifying the problem you are trying to solve (see the "XY" post on meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

An `xsl:for-each` is inappropriate in many places and it is routinely misused by programmers with a procedural background. Instead, you should adopt the functional paradigm. Using `xsl:template` and `xsl:apply-templates` is considered a functional approach.

In your case, it is not necessary to use `xsl:for-each`. Rather, write separate templates for the elements in your input XML. For instance, start with the following:

**EDIT**

As a response to your edit:

> I want to display an HTML file comprising of multiple tables (one table per alert).

Then, include `<table>` in the template that matches individual alerts ( I have edited the code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Alerts</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

Then, write templates for `Alerts`, `AlertType` and so on:

```
<xsl:template match="Alerts|AlertType">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AlertTypeOne">
    <table>
       <!--Decide what to do with this element here-->
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, you did not reveal what you intend your output HTML to look like.

Comment: Added about the details required in HTML.
Also, I am newbie in XSL. In my xml, multiple occurrences of <AlertType> tag may be present. Is apply-templates going to take care of every <AlertType> tag?

Comment: @DarshanMehta It is quite annoying that you keep describing what you need in _words_ rather than simply showing the **HTML output**. Otherwise, everything I can do is making wild guesses.

Comment: Yes, a template takes care of all occurences of an element.

Comment: I have tried to explain HTML output. Please check the edited question.

Comment: As I said: explaining it will not help. Also, you did _not_ add HTML to your question, just something that one might think of as the browser output (whereas you need to show the _source_ HTML).

Answer (score 1):

> based on the first element inside tag, I want to call appropriate xsl
>   file

I don't think you need separate XSL *files*; you can apply different *templates* (within the same stylesheet) to different AlertType elements, based on their child element. The following stylesheet will create a table for each AlertType element, then apply the appropriate template to construct the table's structure (and content, if we had any):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Alerts</h1>
    <xsl:for-each select="Alerts/AlertType">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AlertTypeOne">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AlertTypeTwo">
    <tr>
        <th>Qualification</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AlertTypeThree">
    <tr>
        <th>Credit</th>
        <th>Debit</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
        <td><!--logic --></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Alerts>    
      <AlertType>
         <AlertTypeOne>
            <NewAlert></NewAlert>
         </AlertTypeOne>                
      </AlertType>

      <AlertType>
         <AlertTypeTwo>
            <NewerAlert></NewerAlert>
         </AlertTypeTwo>            
      </AlertType>

      <AlertType>
         <AlertTypeThree>
            <OldAlert></OldAlert>
         </AlertTypeThree>              
      </AlertType>
</Alerts>
```

the following output is received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Alerts</h1>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>                
      </table>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Qualification</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Role</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>            
      </table>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Credit</th>
            <th>Debit</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>              
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```